# Way to remove unwanted tags while paste Microsoft Excel data in WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

While you copy data from Microsoft Excel and then paste into WYSIWYG, it contains lot of  non-common attributes. 
And our existing WYSIWYG does not have any feature to remove those unnecessary attributes of that excel data. I know there are many WYSIWYG Editors which support this feature.

But how can I implement that feature in our existing WYSIWYG editor in an easy step?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest step of all would be to use an existing WYSIWYG editor, such as TinyMCE or CKEditor. Failing that, I'd look at the source code of either of those to see how their pasted HTML cleaning functionality works. Both employ a trick to redirect a paste into an off-screen element where the pasted content is then cleaned before being inserted into the editor's main edit pane.

Comment: We can not switch to another as we are using our in-house built WYSIWYG.

Comment: OK. Then I'd suggest the second option: look at the source code of TinyMCE and/or CKEditor.